Docker error: dial tcp: lookup container-mariadb-coffee on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
My database container was running normally, but after a while it crashed and gave this error. Unfortunately docker doesn't give me a good error message.
If I run the container again, it says that it couldn't find the database, something along the lines of "unknown database <name_of_database>"
This is my docker-compose.yaml:
version: '3.7'

services:
  mariadb:
    container_name: container-mariadb-coffee
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-mariadb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - my-network

  coffee-api:
    container_name: container-coffeeapi
    #image: image-coffeeapi
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Sao_Paulo
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-go
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
      - ./errorLogs:/app/errorLogs
    networks:
      - my-network

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.32.1
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries'
    networks:
      - my-network

volumes:
  errorLogs:
  mariadb-data:

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge

If you want to see my Dockerfile, it looks something like this:
FROM mariadb:latest

COPY ./script.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=my_database
ENV MYSQL_USER=myuser
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypass

EXPOSE 3306

Is there any chance that the error is coming from the "network" property of my database in docker-compose.yaml?
Thank you in advance for any help.

A good simplification would be to remove all of the networks: blocks from the Compose file.  You should also be able to delete container_name:, but you need to change your application's configuration to connect to the Compose service name mariadb.

You can also use a healthcheck.sh as a service dependency.

docker compose logs mariadb can also show log information from the mariadb service to ensure it started correctly.

My docker compose logs mariadb return two warnings, but no error:
[Warning] mariadbd: io_uring_queue_init() failed with errno 95 [Warning] InnoDB: liburing disabled: falling back to innodb_use_native_aio=OFF

@DavidMaze I created a script that deletes the container and runs it again, both the API and the database. When I run them again, the error message changes to "unknown database coffeeprojectdb".

What exactly does that script do?  (Is it more complex than docker compose down && docker compose up -d?)

@DavidMaze Basically it stops and deletes the containers by name and then runs them again with docker-compose up -d
